# System V Semaphore vs Posix Semaphore performance on ARM8

Tags: performance, arm, semaphore, arm64

I am comparing performance of many processes each trying to acquire a semaphore (the semaphore is always in contention) on an ARM8 server with a Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-112

First I used a named posix semaphore and then a system v semaphore where the semaphore set had 1 semaphore.

The performance was 8% worse with the system v semaphore. I know it has worse performance when there is no contention on the semaphore, but I don't understand the performance hit when there is.
When running the same on intel I don't see any difference in performance, but I believe something else is the bottleneck when running on intel.

I want to use System V Semaphore for two reasons, release semaphore in case one of the processes crashed and can increment/decrement by any value instead of +-1

This is the code I wrote for the system v semaphore (initialize is called only from 1 process and I get the same performance hit without the undo flag in wait and post)

```
void init_semaphore(bool initialize, int initCount, int& semId)
{
key_t key;
char* file_path = "/tmp/semv";
char proj_id ='p';
if (initialize)
{
  
    key = ftok(file_path, proj_id);
    if (key == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int flags = IPC_CREAT | 0666;

    semId = semget(key, 1, flags);
    if (semId == -1) {
        perror("semget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    i = semctl(semId, 0, SETVAL, initCount);
    if (i == -1) {
        perror("semctl");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    i = semctl(semId, 0, GETVAL);
    printf("current value of %d is %d\n", semId, i);

}
else
{
    key = ftok(file_path, proj_id);
    if (key == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    semId = semget(key, 1, 0);
    if (semId == -1) {
        perror("semget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
}

void release_semaphore(int semId)
{
int i = semctl(semId, 0, IPC_RMID);
if (i == -1) {
    perror("semctl: semctl failed");
    exit(1);
}
}

void post(int semId)
{
sembuf sops_post[1];
sops_post[0].sem_num = 0;        
sops_post[0].sem_op = 1;
sops_post[0].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
semop(semId, sops_post, 1);
}


void wait(int semId)
{
sembuf sops_wait[1];
sops_wait[0].sem_num = 0;        
sops_wait[0].sem_op = -1;
sops_wait[0].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
semop(semId, sops_wait, 1);
}
```

Comment: This question boils down to 'TSO' versus 'WMO' due to technical differences between System V and Posix semaphores; ('total store order' - x86) and 'weak memory order' ARM/ARM64/IA64), where Risc-V can be either.  The semantic structure for ARM64 and ARM32 are the same as the memory bus technology (AXI, cache controllers, NIC, etc are the same).  AFAIR, there are papers on this with 'futex', etc that discuss the architecture of the semaphore primates in Linux.  However, Linux machinery itself is in a constant state of change.

Answer (score 2):

> Paraphrase: Why is SystemV semaphore contention worse on ARM than Intel?

**TL;DR** - the System V use Linux RCU.  The RCU is a lock free algorithm and it will rely on the processor memory model.  For Intel CPUs, the TSO memory model is much more forgiving than the [ARM memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering#Runtime_memory_ordering).

---

On ARM Linux, `semop` is [implemented as a syscall](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/semop.c#L27).  A syscall has significant overhead.  For the Posix, it is implemented via a call in the vector/kuser table with [__kuser_cmpxchg](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/arm64/kernel/kuser32.S?h=v5.15.6#n42).  This is like the [concept of a vDSO](https://berthub.eu/articles/posts/on-linux-vdso-and-clockgettime/); actually, it is a vDSO on ARM64.  On ARM32, it is mapped with the vector table.

The code for the `semop` is found in [sem.c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206510/cprover-fence-arguments/70217696#70217696).

Just look at the complexity of the code!  One is involving a syscall which is a mode switch and requires complete banking of user state and a possible context switch.  For contention, the posix semaphore will spin in the loop,

```
    .inst   0xe1923f9f              // 1:   ldrex           r3, [r2]
    .inst   0xe0533000              //      subs            r3, r3, r0
    .inst   0x01823e91              //      stlexeq         r3, r1, [r2]
    .inst   0x03330001              //      teqeq           r3, #1
    .inst   0x0afffffa              //      beq             1b
```

It follows with a barrier to ensure observablity of other cores.  The whole mechanics of the `semop` is layered on Linux VFS and RCU.  It makes sense that for system global semaphores, people may want to use System V.  However, for efficiency, the Posix semaphores are far better for single process multi-threaded logic.

The mechanics are night and day when you examine them.  Posix will remain within the user mode and executes only near 100 instructions and stays within a tight loop (like a spin lock) in user space.  The System V is making a syscall, mode change with 1000s of instructions.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206510/cprover-fence-arguments/70217696#70217696) (near the end) to my question for some more on Posix semaphores.  If you plot a histogram of the timing, I would think the System V will show a far higher worse case than the Posix for timing.  8% worse might be a typical/average difference.  The source in sem.c describes a worse case as O(n^2), where I assume 'n' is the number of contending lockers.  For the Posix, some thread will always have the lock and then first successful `strex` will have the update; it is O(1).

---

> The performance was 8% worse with the system v semaphore. I know it
> has worse performance when there is no contention ARM on the semaphore,
> but I don't understand the performance hit when there is. When running
> the same on intel I don't see any difference in performance, but I
> believe something else is the bottleneck when running on intel.

Intel's memory model is TSO, so the RCU code is probably more efficient in the contention case.  For ARM, the memory model is more like the Power.  It is going to need many `smp_wb()` and `smp_rb()`, that probably are not needed on Intel.  These instructions will slow down all cores as they are global and need to sync all cores pipelines.

As Wikipedia's [memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering#Runtime_memory_ordering) shows, other CPUs will show even more performance degradation, such as Alpha.